# How can i use AudioTrack to play mp3 file and also seek to position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audiotrack

Iam trying to develop an application where i can set the speed of music file(mp3) to be set like 1x,1.5x,2x,2.5x like this.but MediaPlayer does not support this feauture unless it is 23 api.How can i use AudioTrack to play this mp3 file and also seek to position.the below code gives me "zzzzzzz" sound.

```
public void playAudio(){
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        int bufferSize = 512;
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        int i = 0;
        byte[] s = new byte[bufferSize];
        try {
            final String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folioreader/audio"+".mp3";
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);

            audioTrack.play();
            while((i = dis.read(s, 0, bufferSize)) > -1){
                audioTrack.write(s, 0, i);

            }
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
            dis.close();
            fin.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? You want to play faster or you want to seek?

Comment: i want to control speed of audio file to 1x,2x,3x,4x

Answer (score 0):

AudioTrack can play uncompressed audio (WAV) not any compressed ones (mp3 or AAC etc.,) You need to call MediaCodec to decode and then use Audio Track to play audio. Refer these links, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html.

For faster playback, give sample rate proportional to the speed that you require. For ex. to play 8kHz audio in 2X rate, give 16kHz in AudioTrack and so on. This is crude way.